# Using $slice with $regex together on subDocument array in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

Hi I am stuck on a problem in mongo. Let me first show you an example of the data. This is a record from my table.

```
{
    "_id": "3691149613248",
    "following": [{
    "content_id": "2584833593728",
    "date": "2015-08-20 12:46:55"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3693447751360",
    "date": "2015-09-11 12:17:55"
    }, {
    "content_id": "2582396936896",
    "date": "2015-09-12 07:04:02"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3697346507456",
    "date": "2015-09-14 09:56:03"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3697755500800",
    "date": "2015-09-16 10:05:51"
    }, {
    "content_id": "2589701320192",
    "date": "2015-09-16 10:51:19"
    }, {
    "content_id": "2585723555136",
    "date": "2015-09-16 11:40:26"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3695996668352",
    "date": "2015-09-16 12:50:25"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3694290368512",
    "date": "2015-09-16 12:50:33"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3691210127552",
    "date": "2015-09-16 13:02:57"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3694134958464",
    "date": "2015-09-16 13:06:17"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3697315148736",
    "date": "2015-09-17 06:58:35"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3692104837824",
    "date": "2015-09-17 12:19:12"
    }, {
    "content_id": "3693400309376",
    "date": "2015-09-22 05:43:04"
    }]
}
```

I want to fetch `following` array with condition that only specific records to fetch i.e. `content_ids` with prefix `369` and fetch number of  `content_id` specified in limit and offset.

I am using `$slice` for fetching records for given limit & offset for `following` array. But how to filter `content_id` along with `$slice`.

My current query:

```
 db.collectionName.find({
    _id: "3691149613248"
}, {
    "following": {
    "$slice": [0, 10]
    }
});
```

This is fetching `following` array with `content_id` that is specified in limit & offset. But it is fetching all `content_id` including prefix `258`& `369` but I only need `content_id` with prefix `369` using mongo query.

Can any one help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with mongo [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to get expected output like:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
    "_id": "3691149613248"  // you can skip this condition if not required
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$following"
}, {
    $match: {
    "following.content_id": {
        $regex: /^369/
    }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "following": {
        $push: "$following"
    }
    }
})
```

If you want to apply [skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to above query then you can easily use it like:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
    "_id": "3691149613248" //use this if you want to filter out by _id
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$following"
}, {
    $match: {
    "following.content_id": {
        $regex: /^369/
    }
    }
}, {
    $skip: 4  // you can set offset here
}, {
    $limit: 3 // you can set limit here
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "following": {
        $push: "$following"
    }
    }
})
```

**EDIT** :

If you are using php version less than 5.4 then query will be as:

```
$search = "369";
$criteria = array(array("$match" => array("_id" => "3691149613248")),
    array("$unwind" => "$following"),
    array("$match" => array("following.content_id" => array("$regex" => new MongoRegex("/^$search/")))),
    array("$skip" => 4), array("$limit" => 3),
    array("$group" => array("_id" => "$_id", "following" => array("$push" => "$following"))));
$collection - > aggregate($criteria);
```

If you are using PHP version greater than 5.3 then just replace `{` and `}` braces with `[` and `]` respectively.

Comment: Thanks Vishwas for replying so quick. I try to give it a shot.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot Vishwas. Sorry I can't upvote your answer (don't have that much reputation points).

Comment: @HemantKumar No Worries. You can accept it as an answer if possible, which will helpful for others in future.

Comment: Is there any way to transform this query into Yii? I am using MongoYii extension by Sammaye.