# Get record from sub-document array in mongo within two ISOdates?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document structure like:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("575912d631b9a4457891d"),
    "events": [
    {
            "sum" : 10;
            "mul" : 100;
            "date": ISODate("2016-06-13T06:55:18.004Z")
    },
    { 
            "sum" : 20;
            "mul" : 10;

            "date": ISODate("2016-06-15T06:56:02.810Z")
    },
    { 
            "sum" : 20;
            "mul" : 10;

            "date": ISODate("2016-06-15T07:56:02.810Z")
    },
    { 
            "sum" : 20;
            "mul" : 10;

            "date": ISODate("2016-06-18T06:56:02.810Z")
    },
    { 
            "sum" : 120;
            "mul" : 10;

            "date": ISODate("2016-06-20T06:56:02.810Z")
    }]
}
```

I want to fetch all sub-document array between 2016-06-13 & 2016-06-20 in PHP from MongoDB. Any help is appreciated.!!

Comment: How do you receive the array ?

Comment: Do you want to filter the `events` array for subdocuments that fall within the given date range **OR** you want to return all the documents that satisfy the date range criteria?

Comment: @splash58 db.collection.find({"_id:ObjectId("575912d631b9a4457891d")})

Comment: @chridam Need to return all sub-documents array that satisfies date range criteria.

Comment: Have you tried doing this thing using `[aggregate-$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)` ?

Comment: @titi23 Yes but didn't  work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everybody..!!

Got the answer from the link [Using $slice with $regex together on subDocument array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711053/using-slice-with-regex-together-on-subdocument-array-in-mongodb).

Just use aggregate(Mongo) & the solution from above link & molded my query according to my need & got desired output.

Query Made In Yii:-

```
     $model = USER::model()->aggregate([
     ['$match' => ["_id" => ObjectId("575912d631b9a4457891d")]],
     ['$unwind' => '$events'],
     ['$match' => ["events.date" => ['$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2016-06-13 00:00:00")),'$lte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2016-06-20 23:59:59"))]]],
    ['$sort' => ["events.date"=>1] ],
     ['$group' => ['_id' => null, 
       "events" => ['$push' => '$events'],
       "totalSum" => ['$sum' => 'events.sum']
       ]]

 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $start = new MongoDate(strtotime(‘2016-06-13 00:00:00’));
 $end = new MongoDate(strtotime(‘2016-06-20 00:00:00’));
 $collection->find(array(“date” => array(‘$gt’ => $start, ‘$lte’ => $end)));
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rajeev for quick response.                                                    Already applied this solution logic but not working..

Comment: $end = new MongoDate(strtotime(‘2016-06-20 23:59:59’)); or  $end = new MongoDate(strtotime(‘2016-06-210 00:00:00’)) with $lt